# How to type the Hash Key?

Tags: r, macos, comments

In `R`, you make comments by using `#`.

I'm using Windows 8 on a MacBook Pro, so the keyboard doesn't have a designated <kbd>#</kbd> key, and the shortcut for an Apple keyboard for the <kbd>#</kbd> key (which is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) doesn't work.

Comment: What keyboard doesn't have <SHIFT>-3 as the pound sign?  Are you confusing some special UTF symbol with the base-ASCII symbol?

Comment: Maybe using a mac to run bootcamp to run windows to run R somehow disables the 3 key. Or could be the shift key since you need both to make a hash. Too many variables to pinpoint the problem

Comment: @CarlWitthoft An Apple Keyboard running on a third party OS, hence my question. I'm talking about the hash key(US pound key), not the pound key(the GBP key).

Comment: @rawr Yes, unfortunately there seems to be too many variables. I'm just surprised not to find any information on it. Using a variety of combinations of `alt`, `shift` and `cmd`, I can only get `3` or `£` from the `3-Key`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I get `£` from using option (alt) + 3; are you using shift? `###`; if nothing works, you can always start > run "charmap" and do it (one of many) work-around ways

Comment: Oh, I've found it.. it's the second `alt` key on the right hand side of the keyboard... Why the two alt keys have different functions I don't know! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On an Apple Keyboard, whilst using a third-party OS such as Windows, you type the `#` symbol by pressing the `2nd Alt key` + `3`.

The first (left hand side) `Alt key` doesn't have a shortcut function.

This applies to all programs (Visual Studio, R, Word etc).

Answer (score 5):

When using Windows the keyboard reverts to a standard Windows keyboard layout, which is different from the Mac layout for some keys. So the hash key is mapped to what is marked as the backslash key \, to the left of the return, and the @ key is mapped to the double inverted comma.

Answer (score 4):

I've got an Apple "Magic Keyboard" on UK settings and can get the hash symbol by holding Command and pressing the Backslash key

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu Xfce on a Macbook, and none of the above answers helped me at all. Then I found I could type a hash character using SHIFT + RIGHT ALT + = twice. It makes sense, because a hash character looks like two '+' signs.

The RIGHT ALT key is listed in my Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout as the 'Compose Key', so if it doesn't work, check what your Compose Key is and try that.